# Put your shoes on and Take your coat off

Tags: idioms, prepositions, word-order

I have often heard the following statements when someone talks about shoes, cloths, etc. I don't know which one is more appropriate or grammatically correct.

> 1. Hey, put your shoes on.
> 2. Hey, put on your shoes.
> 3. Take off your coat, please.
> 4. Take your coat off, please.

Any thoughts?

Can we also say "take out your coat"?

Comment: Have you checked their meaning and use in a dictionary? Here's an appropriate [link](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/take_1#take_1__328).

Comment: "Take out your coat" is grammatically correct, but does not have the same meaning.  It would imply that your coat is put away, e.g. in a closet, and you should remove it for easier access, usually so you can put it on and leave shortly.

Comment: General reference.

Comment: @Irene: My questions is not what it means. My question is in the order of words. But thanks for the link, though.

Comment: The order of words is extremely important with phrasal verbs. For some discussion, see [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/phrasal.html) and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/phrasals.html).

Answer (score 3):

They are all correct. Verbs like "put on" and "take off" are called phrasal verbs. A phrasal verb is a combination of a verb and a preposition/adverb. As particles are separable you may construct as:

> It was hot, so I **took** my jacket **off**.
>   It was hot, so I **took off** my jacket.

For more information please check [Phrasal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above are grammatically correct. You can't say "take out your coat". It doesn't mean the same thing.  You can [check this Oxford entry here for `take`](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/take?q=take).

Comment: What does take out your coat mean? I went to the website and I couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "take out your coat":  "Out" is the opposite of "in" or "inside".  So to be able to take X out (of Y), it must be that X is currently inside Y.  If your coat is inside you, you're not wearing it correctly :)

As Kevin points out, if you just said "take out your coat" without saying what to take it out of, the listener would probably understand that they should take it out of some place where it is stored (a closet, a car, the washing machine).